# How to map a single SSRS parameter to multiple parameters of a stored procedure

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a Stored procedure in MYSQL contain two date parameters`(@FromDate,@ToDate)`.
See Here my requirement is,
In SSRS it will display one date parameter in preview tab.
when i click date it will display that Date only.
how can i achieve this Scenario?
Can anyone explain briefly?

Regards,
Samba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass a single date to what I presume is a "between" parameter, you will probably get zero rows.

Instead, try this:

1. Add a date parameter to your SSRS report.  We'll call it "c"
2. Set the "Fromdate" parameter to "Hidden", and set its default value to `=Parameters!c.Value`
3. Set the "Todate" paramter to "Hidden", and set its default value to `=DATEADD("d",1, Parameters!c.Value)` (adjust the time added as needed)

This should allow the user to only see the "c" parameter, while populating the target parameters in a useful way.

Comment: Hi Leprosy,I did like above points but i try to go preview the report am getting error like below-"the report parameter 'From Date' as default or a valid value that depends on the report parameter 'c'.Forward dependencies are not valid'" Need your help.

Comment: In the list of parameters in the report, is C the first parameter?

Comment: Hi Leprosy,Actually before i have put 'C' is the third parameter,When i make it as first its nicely worked. Thanks

Comment: Happy to help.  If this solved your question, please mark it as "answered".